# Make selected edges equidistant, like you can in Inkscape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

In Inkscape there is a tool where it will make selected objects equidistant. In blender I am trying to find a similar tool. In the example below the tool would make the selected edges equidistant on the y axis. Does it exist?

[image: example]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use ***Loop Tools*** specials to do it. Select one edge of your mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>), then press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Loop Tools*-->*Space*.
[image]

You can enable the ***Loop Tools*** in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). 
[image]

Comment: Awesome. For mine I had to select both edges because it spaced only the vertices on one side.